# -11 error while clBuildProgram in openCL

Tags: windows-7, amd-processor

I have refered all the possible solutions for my query but nothg is working. Am using AMD processor with ATI 3200 graphiccs card which doesnot supports openCL. But due to the special features of openCL , the code is running on CPU itself instead of GPU. But for the kernel code having __local variables , its showing -11 error while clBuildProgram.

give me some solution why I am getting this -11 error???

Thanks in advance. Will be eagerly waiting

Answer (score 0):

Can you post a minimized kernel with a minimized C++ program here? Did you try using the Intel  OpenCL SDK.

If you use the default device and your GPU doesn't support OpenCL, the platform will pick the CPU device.

Comment: Hey @Uday, I actually got the answer for my above given query. with the help of CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG parameter I found out the error in my kernel code.